# Contar letras en una cadena en R con while ()

Tags: r, loops

buenas tardes.

Estoy tratando de hacer un ciclo while, para un conteo de letras.
EL objetivo es obtener el conteo de las primeras 20 letras de una secuencia de ADN.

El Script que tengo es:

```
sec <- "ACGTGCATGACGTAGCTATGCAGTCATACACGTGCATGACGTAGCTATGCAGTCATCGATA"
DNA <- strsplit(sec,"")

C <- 0
T <- 0
G <- 0
conteos <- A+C+T+G
while (conteos < 20) {
  DNA_A <- gsub("A","",DNA)
  A <- nchar(DNA)-nchar(DNA_A)
  print("El número de Adeninas en la secuencia es:")
  print(A)
    DNA_C <- gsub("C","",DNA)
  C <- nchar(DNA)-nchar(DNA_C)
  print("El número de Citocinas en la secuencia es:") 
  print(C)
  DNA_G <- gsub("G","",DNA)
  G <- nchar(DNA)-nchar(DNA_G)
  print("El número de Guaninas en la secuencia es:") 
  print(G)
  DNA_T <- gsub("T","",DNA)
  T <- nchar(DNA)-nchar(DNA_T)
  print("El número de Tiaminas en la secuencia es:") 
  print(T)
  conteos = A+C+T+G
  }
```

El problema que tengo es que el ciclo me esta dando el total de bases nitrogenadas, pero no se detiene en la base 20.

Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

Comment: Comentarios: 1°, acá, quienes intentan responder las preguntas no siempre son de tú área de conocimiento por lo que es complicar la pregunta agregando lenguaje técnico, como por ejemplo _ 20 nucleotidos por base nitrogenada_. 2° Tu código no es replicable, se me cae en la segunda línea (`DNA <- strsplit(DNA,"")`) debido a que no existe el objecto `DNA` Si puedes corregir esos errores se nos hará más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tus comentarios.

Lo que deseo hacer contar las primeras 20 letras de esa cadenas. Pero que me diga cuantas hay de cada letra. 

PERDON: Tengo un error en el script: DNA <- strsplit(sec,"")

Comment: Por último, podrías editar el nombre de la pregunta a algo como: "Contar las primeras 20 letras de una cadena" o las n primeras letras, así si alguien tiene la misma duda le será más fácil llegar a este link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu comentario entiendo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Primero, debes obtener la subsecuencia: una alternativa es `substr`

```
subsec <- substr(sec, 0, 20)
```

Separo los elementos:

```
els <- strsplit(subsec, "")
```

lo anterior lo deja en una lista, la cual podemos "desenlistar" con el comando unlist

```
els <- unlist(els)
```

Y para contar, el comando table

```
tabla <- table(els)
tabla
A C G T 
5 4 6 5
```

Compruebas siempre!
    sum(tabla)
    20

Espero sea lo que necesitas, y en ese caso, espero recuerdes algunos comandos :)

#### Moraleja

La mayoría de las funciones en `R` son vectorizadas ¿esto que significa? que muy muy pocas veces necesitaras del `for` o `while` ;)!

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por los comentarios.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!